# html,JS search field list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JS but have good knowledge in C and HTML and want to create a search box so that when I write something, a drop-down list appears with some results. I already have the code to create the animated search field (which is not mine) and the code to create this search filter list but I don't know how to "connect" them.

Here is the JS part for the search bar filter: (To use it you just need this html code
`<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search article"/>` here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c30L5esq/)

```
$("#searchInput").on('keyup', function() {
  var searchValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  if(searchValue.length > 0) {
    searchAndFilter(searchValue);
  } else {
    $("#articlesearch li").hide();
  }
});

function searchAndFilter(searchTerm) {
  $("#articlesearch li").each(function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
    if (currentText.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#articlesearch li").hide();
});
```

And here it is the link for the search bar fullscreen animation :
https://codepen.io/suez/pen/obpLvy/

And what I want is that when I use this search bar animation, I can actually search through a list and it will show me results that match what I typed in a dropdown.

Thank you !

Comment: Try this jQuery UI Widget https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Try This.  https://jsfiddle.net/a7u9fo9q/1

Comment: I know how to make the "js filter code" but I don't know how to add it to the js animation code that I've found in the codepen.io link

Comment: @Waterploof, I think you need something like this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/oNXLYrx .. Am I right?? I really suspect the accepted answer because you want to combine both animated search with the  list items like which I have given in the link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $("#articlesearch>li");
  list.hide();

  $(document).on('input', "#searchInput", function() {
    /* searchAndFilter($(this).val()) */
    list.hide();
    var searchTerm = ($(this).val() + '').toUpperCase();
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
      list.each(function() {
        var currentText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
        if (currentText.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
          $(this).show();
        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ravinila/ghovnzty/13

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for is autocomplete for search input. For that we have to use [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) plugin. You can go with the link on the plugin and [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pavankumar_kori/pen/BaNzpZP) example link. There are multiple example [demos](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) in the link.

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

```html
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. 
In fact, I just want this codepen: https://codepen.io/suez/pen/obpLvy/ to work. So what is missing is to implement the code that you showed me in this codepen.

Comment: @Waterploof It can be implemented. As you are new to js. Try to implement by reading document and demos. If u cant implement I will do and show you. It is easy read the document you will come to know.

Comment: I tried and I'm able to implement it alone but I don't see how to implement it with this codepen codepen.io/suez/pen/obpLvy. I tried but in vain. 
I'll be happy if you could show it to me to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: OK I am stuck with work. But I will implement it and show. It will take some. as I am stuck in office work.

Comment: If this is the solution you are looking for. Then please accept the answer and up-vote.

Comment: Thank you but I think you forgot to give the link of the solution ?

Comment: Ya today i will provide